# Maximum of weighted sum of exponentials

Tags: polynomials, optimization, roots, computational-complexity, nonlinear-optimization

Given a function
$$f(t) := \sum_k a_k e^{b_k t} $$
for some $b_k < 0$, we want to find maximum of $f(t)$ over $t > 0$ algorithmically.

A solution would be to calculate $f'(t)$ and and then convert $e^{-t}$ to a new variable, say $z$, and find roots of a polynomial with (potentially) non-integer exponents. Is there any better algorithm in terms of computational complexity?

Comment: some $a_k$ are positive, and some are negative?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Newton’s algorithm is the way to go.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1527949)

Comment: I see. The question is "Is there any better algorithm in terms of computational complexity?" so I'll modify my answer.

Comment: So, is there any better algorithm? Or can we say there is no better one?